# 3d object rotating from one given image

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing

There is a game Stronghold 2001 with sprite graphics. Movable units in the game has different animations that consist of several frames. Each frame is usually represented by 8 sprites from different angles of view on the unit. A sptite is approximately 50x50 colored image.

The first problem is that some animations are represented by sprites from only one angle of view. And there is a need to somehow draw sprites for other 7 angles of view for each frame of these animations. The second problem is that 8 angles of view for the units are not enough. I want each unit has 16 angles of view, so 8 more angles of view for each frame are needed to be drawn.

So, basically I need to rotate 3d assymetric object with artifacts of casting from and to sprite. I am not an expert at machine learning. First idea was to make a perceptron with input of one sprite and rotating angle, so output would be a sprite with rotated unit. But the training set is not too big. Is a way to combine two problems better? Or I should build a separate model for each case? Could it be good to train the model on all types of units? I don`t have ideas how to build effective model that is able to find hidden relations of 3d object rotation in plane sprites. Which architecture of neural network could be the best solution?

Comment: are you sure the stats.SE is a relevant question to this community?

Comment: As @spiridon_the_sun_rotator mentioned, have you considered other SEs like StackOverflow or some game development SE?

Comment: @Patrick Coulombe, I am sorry for confusing theme in the beginning. I think the question refers to machine learning mostly and I thought it would be better to not put my own limits to the question. I hope that machine learning specialists will answer with their view at the possibility of solving the problems or give me any suggesion, direction